# Prerender not waiting for dynamic page title and meta tags rendering

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, seo, prerender

I was integrating [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) with an angular-node application for SEO purpose just as an POC, My application resides [HERE](http://testseonode-datahouse.rhcloud.com/), The good part is all the three links are crawled so I get 200 ok for all links tested [here](http://tools.seochat.com/tools/online-crawl-google-sitemap-generator/), However the problem which Im facing is the title and meta tags are not captured for each link

I've used {{}} in title tags similarly for description also which gets reflected on the loaded page but not while crawler crawls. You can check the page source for code, I tried using the

> window.prerenderReady

but still not able to make it work, any suggestions or how this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working fine here:

http://testseonode-datahouse.rhcloud.com/?_escaped_fragment_=

So it looks like the crawler you used just doesn't crawl using the escaped fragment crawling protocol. You have to match those crawlers by user agent in the middleware.